# How to implement JWS (RFC 7797) signature validation in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jwt, jose

For a contactless payment implementation in a Ruby on Rails project, I need to verify the signature of a postback. The signature is a JSON Web Signature (JWS) with a detached payload, following the [RFC 7797](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7797) standard.

I've looked the [ruby-jose](https://github.com/potatosalad/ruby-jose) gem as well as [ruby-jwt](https://github.com/jwt/ruby-jwt), but neither one seems to implement this specification.

Has anyone done this before, or can anyone point me in the right direction?